# Comparative without following noun

Tags: ellipsis, comparative-constructions

> Travelers will have **longer** to switch over to a REAL ID, avoiding for now what many fliers anticipated would be a major hassle.

The original article is [this](https://www.wsj.com/articles/real-id-drivers-license-homeland-security-11670255144?st=svd195089zmomy9&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink).

I understand it as '... have **longer time** to switch over ...'. Can the noun be omitted after comparative or is it a different structure which I don't understand?

('I have more.' makes sense because 'more' is not a comparative but can be a pronoun or adverb.)

Comment: "Longer" can only be an adverb in your first example, but an adjective in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a noun has been omitted here. However, note that if we include the noun "time", then a determiner is required:

> Travelers will have [[a]] longer [[time]] to switch over . . .

We can do the same with some other adjectives, as well. For example:

> The travelers from Argentina went [[a]] further [[distance]] than the travelers from Brazil.

Keep in mind that that is possible because the missing words can be easily inferred from context. In a sentence such as this one, we could not omit any words:

> The traveler from Argentina has a bigger suitcase than the traveler from Brazil.

Comment: In the expression "They went further," why do you judge "further" an adjective rather than an adverb?

Comment: @Chaim I think *longer* can be an adverb too and the question seems to be not the problem of ellipsis. But StackExchange shows a blistering message when I attempted to delete this question. Of course I appreciate both of you Marc and Chaim.

Comment: @Chaim Yes, it could certainly be construed as an adverb, too.